# If depth buffer was reversed, would glDepthFunc need to be reversed as well?

Tags: c++, opengl, depth-buffer

In a project for a portable system, I am experiencing a strange error with setting up 3D depth rendering. In the system SDK it uses a ported version of OpenGL 2.0 called GU. The code is almost completely the same save for some of the initialization. An oddity of the system is that the depth buffer is inversed (i.e. near = far, far = near). Does this mean that the depth function used is also opposite?

Instead of

```
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
```

would I use

```
glDepthFunc(GL_GEQUAL);
```

Thanks very much for any responses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to further testing, the problem is that it must be reversed as the data stored in the buffer will only pass the test the other way around.